# How come LogMeIn is able to connect to an Office computer even when the VPN client does not run?

Tags: vpn, remote-control, openvpn, logmein

I am using LogMeIn to control my office machine (Win 7) from home (Win XP). In order to do that, I installed the OpenVPN client to connect to the VPN server at the office's intranet.

The configuration runs smoothly but I just discovered that I can logmein to that computer even when the VPN client is disconnected **or not even running**.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximately like this:

Your computer at work is allowed outbound connections. When you install the Logmein client it connects to a server controlled by Logmein (the company).

When you what to access your work computer you connect to the logmein server. The server then tells the client software on your work computer that you want to connect and the client establishes a connection between your home computer->logmein server->work computer.

Comment: But of course... same thing like Skype. The fact that upon startup it is the *remote* computer that establishes the connection with the service center means that now the firewall assumes that it is OK for the external traffic from that source to pass into the intranet. Thanks for reminding the obvious.

Comment: Does VNC work the same way or is it more peer-to-peer symmetrical connection, which will require the VPN connection first?

Comment: OTOH, this behavior actually means that I can log into my office computer from any web enabled computer - not just the one I have OpenVPN installed on - which can be convinient at times.

Comment: And, best thing is that this makes my previous question irrelevant: http://superuser.com/questions/348607/is-it-possible-to-route-internet-traffic-when-openvpn-connection-is-active